# Is the 20 cm Lightning to 30-pin adapter functionally different than the shorter all in one part?

Tags: lightning

Are the two male Lightning to female 30-pin adapters that Apple is selling functionally equivalent (other than the fact that one has a 20 cm cable between the endpoints)?

[image: Lightning to 30-pin Adapter] [Part MD823ZM/A](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD823ZM/A/lightning-to-30-pin-adapter)
[image: Lightning to 30-pin Adapter (0.2 m)] [Part MD824ZM/A](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD824ZM/A/lightning-to-30-pin-adapter-02-m)

Comment: They are functionally identical.

Comment: One would think given the bare information we have at present, but the cost differential has me suspicious that perhaps there's something different about the two.

Comment: The model numbers say otherwise. The only difference is 823 vs 824. Anyway, since when has cost had anything to do with feature-set? :-)

Comment: 10 bucks for 20 cm of cable, yeap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - they are equivalent in all measurable aspects other than length. Sometimes we find out things that don't make the public specifications about Apple products, but these two items don't seem to fall into that category.

Comment: I feel funny making this comment *to* a moderator, but: this is a pretty weak answer. :) Do you have any details that back up this assertion?

Comment: I've searched a bit and if I'm ever proven to be wrong I'll be happy to have someone answer that or edit this answer. Also - Apple's public specs are clear and haven't been changed in a month's time, so all signs point to my answer. Sometimes the initial page listing what each device does is subject to change - but in this case the tech specs are solid and unchanging. I was tempted to just delete this entirely, but sometimes even seeing the simplest question on the site helps a bunch of people. Big thanks for questioning me - there's an edit button if you can help make either Q or A better :)